# Tag list filter animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, transition

Stack overflow community, With some web resources and help from some user from this great community the followed tag list filter was created. It's great to sort any kind of data with as many tag as you would like.

I would like to ask you to have to have a look at the result and suggest how some animation can be added to it or maybe some external library, so the appearance and restructuring of blocks would look more smoother and natural.

For example when I was trying to find something similar to this idea of filtering I found this great [Magento plugin](http://docs.haundodesign.com/magnet/#animation_types), the animation they have made are amazing, but unfortunately this plugin does not allow to filter data in 2 or more different tag lists.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Composition</h2> 
<ul class="filter" id="composition">
    <li><a data-value="all" class="selected">All</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="landscape">Landscape</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="portait">Portait</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="square">Square</a> </li>
</ul>

<h2>People</h2>
<ul class="filter" id="people">
    <li><a data-value="all" class="selected">All</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="people">People</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="nopeople">No People</a></li>
</ul>

<h2>Theme</h2>
<ul class="filter" id="theme">
    <li><a data-value="all" class="selected">All</a> </li>
    <li><a data-value="Nature">Nature</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="Fashion">Fashion</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="Mountains">Mountains</a></li> 
    <li><a data-value="Sea">Sea</a></li>    
</ul>

<h2>Data to filter</h2> 
    <div class="item landscape people Nature"></div> 
    <div class="item portait nopeople Fashion"></div> 
    <div class="item landscape people Mountains"></div> 
    <div class="item portait people Sea"></div> 
    <div class="item square people Mountains"></div> 
    <div class="item landscape people Fashion"></div> 
    <div class="item square nopeople Sea"></div> 
    <div class="item landscape nopeople Mountains"></div> 
    <div class="item portait people Fashion"></div> 
    <div class="item square nopeople Sea"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
   list-style: none; 
}

div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("ul.filter li a")
    .on('click', function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .closest('ul')
            .find('a')
            .removeClass('selected');
        $this
            .addClass('selected');
        var selector = [];
        $('ul li a.selected')
            .each(function() {
                var selectedValue = $(this).data('value');
                if (selectedValue !== 'all') {
                    selector.push(selectedValue);
                }
            });
        $(".item")
            .hide();
        if (selector.length) {
            $('.item.'+ selector.join('.')).show();
        } else {
            $(".item")
                .show();
        }
    });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you think about this?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/15/)

**CSS**

```
li{
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".item").css("height","0");
if (selector.length) {
    $('.item.'+ selector.join('.')).css("height", "15px");
}
```

I do find the solution for the problem at hand (using css classes to filter data) a bit weird. You should add the data to the JS and inject that in the html.

Comment: Its just a concept, the absolute height might be bad for longer items, but animations don't work with height:auto

Comment: Hello, Brett I am not sure if i did it well (https://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/14/). But anyway first I would like to apologize, because I have loaded the old version of fiddle for people, in my case this plug-in sorts blocks with photos, I was actually trying to make something similar to http://docs.haundodesign.com/magnet/#animation_types . Maybe you have some ideas how to achieve something like the animation this guys have made?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/22vh08ah/15/ did forget to update fiddle, pls have a look at the saved one :)

Comment: if the answer is correct please mark it as the answer.